# WordPress sitemap with Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, php, archives, custom-post-type-archives, sitemap

This is a really neat idea but I'd like to expand upon it. In his post, David Kennedy writes out some code to allow a basic `wp_list_pages` type feature for [Custom Post Types to use as a sitemap](http://davidakennedy.com/blog/2011/06/21/sitemap-with-custom-post-types/). His code is as follows:

```
<h2 id="posts">My Post Type</h2>
    <ul>
    <?php 
        $terms = get_terms( 'my_taxonomy', 'orderby=name' );
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            echo "<li><h3>".$term->name."</h3>";
            echo "<ul>";
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'my_posttype',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'my_taxonomy',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $term->slug
                    )
                )
            );
            $new = new WP_Query($args);
                while ($new->have_posts()) {
                    $new->the_post();
                    echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
                }
            echo "</ul>";
            echo "</li>";
        } ?>
        </ul>
```

I like this idea but am wanting to take it a bit further. It'd be great to add depth, or levels of hierarchy, and to show parent/child relationship results instead of listing Custom Post Types alphabetically. In other words, mimic more of the functions that `wp_list_pages` offers.

Is there an easier way to do this or is there functionality in WordPress that already does what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick crack at it, which should work in two level depth:

```
<h2 id="posts">My Post Type</h2>
<ul>
<?php
    $not_in = array(); //to avoid naming the same post over and over
    //get top level terms
    $Parent_terms = get_terms( 'my_taxonomy', array('orderby' => 'name','parent' => 0));
    foreach ($Parent_terms as $term) {
        echo "<li><h3>".$term->name."</h3>";
        echo "<ul>";
        //get all children of each term
        $child_terms = get_terms( 'my_taxonomy', array('orderby' => 'name','parent' => $term->ID));
        foreach ((array)$child_terms as $t){
            echo "<li><h4>".$t->name."</h4>";
            echo "<ul>";
            $args = array(
                'post__not_in' => $not_in,
                'post_type' => 'my_posttype',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'my_taxonomy',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $t->slug
                    )
                )
            );
            $new = new WP_Query($args);
            while ($new->have_posts()) {
                $new->the_post();
                $not_in[] = $post->ID;
                echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
                //here you should check for children posts and output them 
            }
            echo "</ul>";
            echo "</li>";
        }
        //get all posts that are only listed in top level term
        $args = array(
            'post__not_in' => $not_in,
            'post_type' => 'my_posttype',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'my_taxonomy',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $term->slug
                    )
                )
        );
        $new = new WP_Query($args);
        while ($new->have_posts()) {
            $new->the_post();
            $not_in[] = $post->ID;
            echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
            //here you should check for children posts and output them 
        }
        echo "</ul>";
        echo "</li>";
    } ?>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Neat, although I can't seem to get this working correctly when changing the proper values as reflected in David's post. I'll keep playing around and seeing if I can make this page work with the given code and give you my feedback. Also, if I wanted to add a third level depth, what would be required?

Comment: It appears the problems in your code lie with the `get_terms` parameter where parent is equal to a value. I used a PHP validator to show me any errors and fixing those two lines allowed the page to at least show up, but it's not populating with any of my Custom Post Type posts.

Comment: Create a pastebin of the code you are using and ill take a look.

Comment: Oh, actually, I made no significant changes to your code. All I did was change to `'parent=0'` in both lines, which allowed the page to render the code and show something. Nothing else about your version of the code changed.

Comment: you can't use part array and part string for arguments so it makes no sense, no I've just check it it seems to work fine so if you want, show me your exact code and i'll see whats wrong

Comment: Okay, I found my problem! I entered the wrong taxonomy label. Once I updated it to a proper name, it worked. Now my question is how to show children/parent relationships of individual Custom Post Type posts. I created two CPT posts, each parents with one child each (so a total of 4 CPT posts). In the list that this code spits out, I don't see those children listed anywhere. That's what I was originally hoping this code would do, although maybe I was confused about what it was doing in the first place.

Comment: I created a screenshot here: http://i.imgur.com/0QQ0G.png. There are two taxonomy names: city and suburb. You'll see two links which are city names. Both of those cities should have a child listed under each. I don't understand why the lineage of hierarchy starts with the taxonomy and then lists both taxonomy names under each taxonomy name. It's redundant?

Comment: Well, first to add the children of a post you would need to create another query which gets all children of each post, and as for the taxonomy , that really depends on how you created your taxonomies.

Comment: PHP is not my strong area so while I know the logic that you are stating, I'm not sure how I would query the posts to find their hierarchy. As for the Taxonomies, there isn't anything special about them. Here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/ANeeH.png  I just don't get why each taxonomy name has every instance of each taxonomy name down the chain. It shouldn't do this. Ultimately, I was hoping this would work in a completely different way, where, in my example, "Gardena" was in the same place that the first instance of "city" is, and that children would appear below it.

Comment: I see what you mean, i fixed the syntax of get_terms arguments so try it, and also I've added a comment where you should list children posts.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll need to do research to figure out how to do that part; hopefully I can find the answer. As for the change to `get_terms`, the result of the code hasn't changed the output. It looks exactly the same.

Comment: Maybe this ultimately won't do what I was hoping it would. Here's a screenshot of what I was really looking for. http://i.imgur.com/LdbW6.jpg Every item, including the title "Torrance", is a link to Custom Post Type post. Each colored description is a category type. You can see this is kinda how `wp_list_pages` already works, but since it doesn't include CPTs, I was hoping to find something like this elsewhere. Should I create a new question to do this?

Comment: For its intended purpose, I think this is a good solution. I'll mark it as the answer b/c it was a very acceptable answer. Thank you for your help!